# Creating a ListView layout from an ArrayList

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

What I want to do in one of my tabs in my application is have a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) of contacts.  Though, in that example, the ListView is made from an array of Strings.  Is there a way that I can create one of those using the values from an ArrayList?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually did some more Google'ing of this, and I found this:

`String str [] = (String []) neoFriends.toArray (new String [neoFriends.size ()]);`

Where `neoFriends` is the ArrayList<String>.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

This tutorial explains everything, including how to do the xml files and java files.

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Create an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and pass in the ArrayList in the [constructor][2].

[2]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, T[])

Comment: What should I put for the `int textViewResourceId` ?

Comment: I think that would be the resource of the text view that represents one of the items in the list. R.id.list_item